# Do I need a Firefox plugin or an extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-plugin

I need to read every url that loads into the navigation bar of firefox (either by type in or by clicking a link), pass them through a filter and decide if allow the url to open or not.

I have some experience on firefox extensions but not with plugins.

Do I need to do it using extensions or plugins for this?

I currently have a BHO for IE that does this, and I get the URLs using the web browser events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension would be just fine. For what you want to do, you need `nsIObserverService`, and `http-on-modify-request` observer.

Comment: or alternatively, `nsIURIContentListener`. But in my (admittedly somewhat limited) experience, the way you're suggesting is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/) (See the video)